Split number into range of numbers
I'm coming from a dev background and need to build a specific shipping calculator. But I find it difficult to figure out the correct algorithm for my case.
I'm sure someone out there has had a similar question before, but I can't even find the correct keywords to search for the concept.
So, suppose there are some weight ranges, ie:



Weight
Cost




1
1.2 USD


5.01 - 10 lbs
6.25 USD


10.01 - 15 lbs
9.2 USD


15.01 - 20 lbs
10.90 USD



Now, suppose a parcel weighing 22 lbs. This would cost 13.30 USD as its weight can be analyzed to 20 + 1 + 1, for which the price is 10.90 + 1.2 + 1.2 = 13.30 USD
For a more complex scenario, suppose a parcel weighing 53 lbs. This can be analyzed to 20 + 20 + 10 + 1 + 1 + 1, for which the price is
10.90 + 10.90 + 6.25 + 1.2 + 1.2 + 1.2 = 31.65 USD
How is this called in mathematics? And do you have any algorithm in mind to perform that in PHP?
The easiest part I can think of is that the ranges need to be calculated upside down, from the largest to the smallest.

There is no name for this. Your "upside down" calculation is a good algorithm, and easy to write. Are you sure of the specs? As written a four pound package ships for $8 and a five pound package for $7.

I would consider this similar to variants of the Knapsack Problem or the Bin Packing Problem, but where the goal here is not to have the highest total "value", but rather to have the smallest subject to the constraint that the knapsack must be totally "filled."  Such problems are often quite difficult in general, but in practice since your costs per unit seem to follow a trend, the "greedy algorithm" might turn out correct in many cases.

As alluded to however, a 24 pound package is cheaper to consider it broken up as 19+5 than it is to consider it as 20+1+1+1+1, a clear example of where the greedy algorithm fails.

@JMoravitz sorry, I wrote the question on my cellphone, so I didn't use the precise costs, etc... At first I missed a whole range (10-15), and secondly I messed with the price cost of each range. Not that there may not be a case for the precise costs that an upside-down approach might not be the most profitable one (for the customer), but at least I have to start from something! Anyway, I'm updating my initial post with the correct ranges/cost. Sorry for the confusion.

@JMoravitz With the OPs correct costs there's no longer any need for bin packing sophistication.

The greedy algorithm (what you call "calculating upside down" is indeed what you want here. That's because with the (correct) figures in the table the cost per pound is always greater for smaller shipped weights.

Ethan can you help me locate an algorithm that with a little touch up would fit my case please?

There's nothing more to :"locate". Your examples are essentially the pseudocode for the algorithm. At each step use as much of the cheapest rate (largest chunk) as possible. You can write that in a loop, or recursively.

I did Ethan. At some point I was stuck in an edge case, but then I found my way through!
